# Drying up code with abstract class in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Let's say I have a warehouse with some "stuff" and I have some minions to run around this warehouse:

```
public class Warehouse {
    public T GetItemInfo<T>(int id) where T : IItem, new() {}

    public int AddItem<T>(T item) where T : IItem {}

    public int RemoveItem<T>(int id) where T : IItem, new() {}
}
```

with minion interface:

```
public interface IMinion<T> where T : IItem {
    T GetItemInfo(int id);
    int AddItem<T>(T item);
    int RemoveItem<T>(int id);
}
```

The `PartMinion` comes first:

```
public class PartMinion : IMinion<Part> {
    protected Warehouse wh;

    public PartMinion(Warehouse wh) {
        this.wh = wh;
    }

    public Parts GetItemInfo(int id) {
        return wh.GetItemInfo<Part>(id);
    }

    public int AddItem(int id) {
        return wh.AddItem<Part>(id);
    }

    public int RemoveItem(int id) {
        return wh.RemoveItem<Part>(id);
    }
}
```

But, the `FurnitureMinion` is mostly the same as the `PartMinion`:

```
public class FurnitureMinion : IMinion<Furniture> {
    protected Warehouse wh;

    public FurnitureMinion(Warehouse wh) {
        this.wh = wh;
    }

    public Furniture GetItemInfo(int id) {
        return wh.GetItemInfo<Furniture>(id);
    }

    public int AddItem(int id) {
        return wh.AddItem<Furniture>(id);
    }

    public int RemoveItem(int id) {
        return wh.RemoveItem<Furniture>(id);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Parts> GetParts(int id) {
        var query = "SELECT * FROM Parts " +
                    "JOIN FurnitureParts ON Parts.ID = FurnitureParts.PartID " +
                    "WHERE FurnitureParts.FurnitureID = ?";
        var result = wh.Query<Parts>(query, id);
        return result;
    }
}
```

So I'd like to `Abstract` away the duplicate code between the two, but I can't quite get the syntax right:

```
public abstract class AbstractMinion : IMinion<T> {
    protected Warehouse wh;

    public AbstractMinion(Warehouse wh) {
        this.wh = wh;
    }

    public Parts GetItemInfo(int id) {
        return wh.GetItemInfo<T>(id);
    }

    public int AddItem(int id) {
        return wh.AddItem<T>(id);
    }

    public int RemoveItem(int id) {
        return wh.RemoveItem<T>(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a generic parameter to a class. You also need a `where` constraint, because this constraint exists on interface `IMinion`:

```
public abstract class AbstractMinion<T> : IMinion<T>
    where T : IItem  
{
    protected Warehouse wh;

    public AbstractMinion(Warehouse wh) {
        this.wh = wh;
    }

    public T GetItemInfo(int id) {
        return wh.GetItemInfo<T>(id);
    }

    public int AddItem(int id) {
        return wh.AddItem<T>(id);
    }

    public int RemoveItem(int id) {
        return wh.RemoveItem<T>(id);
    }
}
```

So for `PartMinion` your class would look like this:

```
public class PartMinion : AbstractMinion<Part> {
    public PartMinion(Warehouse wh) :base(wh){
    }
}
```